# Different app name

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

Is it possible to have different names for the app launch icon and for the name used when showing native alerts?

For example my app name is "Photo Filters" but it's too long for the launch icon so I want the name "Filters" under the app icon, but I still want the full name "Photo Filters" when used in native ios alerts such as:

> 'Photo Filters' would like to access your photos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately that's not possible.

Both the home screen name and the notification name are specified by the same plist key `CFBundleDisplayName`.